# .htaccess works in the localhost webroot. How to do also works in a localhost subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess

A development proyect in http://localhost/myfolder has references to /assets/css/styles.css which is the site in production.

I want to call it like: http://localhost/myfolder/

I have this .htaccess in apache webroot folder c:\wamp\www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And it works ok when is, as I said in webroot folder.

When I  move this .htaccess to /myfolder/.htaccess it does nothing.

What I have to change in this .htaccess to work also inside myfolder?

Thank you

Comment: No sorry. styles.css was only an example.

All the site is inside /myfolder, nothing in webroot. The webroot of my localhost has folders with other projects:

The site looks like this:

/myfoldler/assets/css/styles.css
/myfolder/assets/js/functions.js

etc...

I need to move the .htaccess in / to /myfolder to have a .htacces for each project.

Comment: The puporse of the /myfolder/.htaccess is simulate that a request of /assets (o any folder) is in /myfolder/assets when the .htaccess in under /myfolder instead of in /.htaccess.

I want that each project has its own .htaccess inside os its folder.

The questions is that I download a web project that all its paths is refering to /, and the project on my localhost is under its respective folder.

Comment: As I previously commented that if URL on your page is `/assets` then .htaccess in sub-folder cannot manage it.

Comment: Ok, its imposible then. You give me the key, and now I find other solution.
Thank you. I post the Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's imposible to manage absolute paths refereds to root from a subfolder (as Anubhava said), I decide to focus the problem with an /.htaccess and a RewriteCond that work only when we request the specific subfolder.

SOLUTION: (/.htacces finally is in root folder).

```
RewriteEngine on

# Configuración Myfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Fix is the line below  ---- FIX ------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myfolder/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /myfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the other way, without the rewrite condition, it was affecting all requests.

This is better fix than the subfolder one, because you can download the production .htaccess and have no need to touch it.

Hope this help to others.